# Easy digital downloads - Form custom (add / remove / hide fields)

Tags: easy-digital-downloads

I want to create an e-commerce shop with : WP, Easy digital downloads and Frontend submissions.

To do so, I need to customize forms. As an example: I need to add & remove (or hide) fields on the fes_registration_form  without breaking functions behind it.

I don't have a good vision of how the easy digital downloads plugin works so I don't know where to do my updates (don't want to break everything).

Could you please tell me how to proceed to add and remove fields on the fes_registration_form ?

I need to do the same job on the profile form and on the new product ones.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add and remove form fields for the profile and product submission via the built in form builder. There is a simple drag and drop system.

https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/962-frontend-submissions-form-builder

For further custom work you would need to get your hands dirty. I have just completed a major project in totally changing some functions within the forms. This involves a combination of hooks, filters and extending some of the classes provided by the FES extension.